# How to recover Sharepoint groups "Everyone" and "Everyone except external users" that were deleted through PowerShell?

Tags: azure, sharepoint, active-directory, office365, sharepoint-online

How to recover Sharepoint groups "Everyone" and "Everyone except external users" that were deleted through PowerShell?

I'm about to launch an intranet made on a communication site, the launch is close but I can't put the group “Everyone” and “Everyone except external users”.

My organization's information security team excluded these two groups citing security reasons, they were deleted via Sharepoint Shell but I don't have the code executed here.

I would like to know, how do I recover these groups that were deleted?

Because I need them to give access to all employees of the organization.

If I can't recover, I'll have to add users one by one to the visitor group.

I need to put these two groups inside the sharepoint site visitors group.

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHPF0.png)]

Thank you very much in advance

I've already looked at the Azure groups to see if I could recover them there.

but in Azure there is no dynamic group with all employees in the organization, only departmental groups.

Comment: This is probably what you're looking for: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/11/sharepoint-online-enable-disable-everyone-group-using-powershell.html